# How to make a link - link to a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a carousel for a Tumblr blog and there are separate DIVs for each blog post, but there is also a DIV for info like name/description etc.. How would I make a button that slid to that DIV when clicked? The layout is [here](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com) and the one that would be the description has a "2" next to the text. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Wrong link, maybe? I see nothing on the linked site (at: http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com/) that matches your description.

Comment: It's a sliding carousel. Click next and previous to navigate DIVs. On the first div with the picture of the black outfit click previous. I accidentally took away the yellow on the 2. Sorry :(

Answer (score 5):

If you give the div an id, then you can use the id value as an anchor, so

```
<div id="foo">something</div>
```

coupled with

```
<a href="#foo">click me</a>
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Thanks for the fix, herbalessence.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery Slide To](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/slideto)

Answer (score 0):

they are called anchors :

```
<a href="#anchorName">go to div</div>
<a name="anchorName">Example<a>
```

of course having it gradually move down to a point can be achieved with moveto in javascript

Comment: I'm the biggest airhead in the world haha sorry :(